# hg add whole directory despite being listed in the .hgignore

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, hgignore

I have two branches in my mercurial repository with the same .hgignore file: `dir/`

One branch (development) should ignore this directory, while the other (release) should *not* ignore it. I know I can use `hg add dir/somefile` despite the entry in the .hgignore file. But now I would like to add the whole directore recursively.

I searched for that and tried

```
hg add dir    # does not add anything
hg add dir*   # does not add anything
hg add dir/   # does not add anything
hg add dir/*  # only adds the files in dir but not in sub-directories
hg add dir/** # only adds the files in dir but not in sub-directories
```

But that thas not work recursively. I could use `add dir/* dir/*/* dir/*/*/*` and so on, but that is annoying. Is there another wildcard I have to use instead or maybe another way to accomplish this?

PS: I would like to avoid to change the .hgignore.

Comment: Why not temporarily change the `.hgignore` locally, and revert it after? You do not need to check it in...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the meantime, I was able to come up with—what seems to be—a solution:

```
hg add --dry-run --verbose `hg status --ignored --no-status --exclude **.DS_Store dir/`
```

This shows a list of files that it would add. If you really want to add them, use the following command:

```
hg add `hg status --ignored --no-status --exclude **.DS_Store dir/`
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `find`, you can do something like the following:

```
find docs -exec hg add {} \;
```

Whenever running commands with find it's always nice to do a dry run first, so I generally stick an `echo` in front of the command first:

`find docs -exec`**`echo`**`hg add {} \;`

If you need to add enough files that performance is a concern, you can use `+` instead of `\;`, which will append all matching filenames to the same command instead of running the command once for each filename.  For `hg add` this is not likely to be an issue, but it's important for understanding how `find` works.

`find docs -exec hg add {}`**`+`**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `.hgignore` will ignore anything that is not a full path to a file and is respected even when evaluating patterns. There's [a post on StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26770/generate-a-list-of-files-from-a-file-containing-a-series-of-globbing-patterns/26817) that contains alternatives that you could use (assuming that you did not want to change `.hgignore`)

Comment: I tried these file sets already but was not able to come up with a working solution.

Comment: You might take a look at my own solution, it seems to work so far.